# Merge Vertical Table to Horizontal table in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to merge a vertical table to a horizontal table in excel with logics. I do not know where to start in excel. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Horizontal Table:**

```
| Node     | Volume         | Disk Size | Disk Space Used |
| -------- | -------------- | --------- | --------------- |
| A        | E:\            | 140.00GB  | 138.22GB        |
| A        | C:\            | 119.90GB  | 83.97GB         |
```

**Vertical Table:**

```
| Node     | CPU Count   | CPU Load  |
| -------- | ----------- | --------- |
| A        | 8           | 1.43%     |
```

**The Table I wanted:**

```
| Node     | CPU Count   | CPU Load  | C Disk Size | C Disk Space Used | D Disk Size | C Disk Space Used | 
| -------- | ----------- | --------- | ----------- | ----------------- | ----------- | ----------------- | 
| A        | 8           | 1.43%     |  119.90GB   | 138.22GB          | 119.90GB    | 83.97GB           |
```

I don't use excel much. Any idea or advice in the direction of how to solve this would be great.
Is this even achievable in excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved, Vlookup function don't work in my case -(because Vlookup only can look up one field at a time). however, I got a workaround to archived something similar.

1. Merge the tables. [excel merge table](https://www.excel-university.com/vlookup-return-multiple-matching-rows-and-columns/#:%7E:text=Well%2C%20VLOOKUP%20is%20designed%20to,value%20from%20a%20single%20column.)
2. Then use Pivot Table function.

thanks a million for the help.